# neo4j admin import csv with multiple labels fails to parse labels when array delimiter are enabled

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

The default import `bin/neo4j-admin import --database movies1 --nodes=import/movies.csv` works fine.

> NOTICE: you must execute `CREATE DATABASE movies1` from the browser to see the created database
> The result looks like:

[image]

However, when enabling array columns using `bin/neo4j-admin import --database movies2 --array-delimiter="|" --nodes=import/movies.csv`, neo4j admin import csv tool no longer is parsing the multiple labels correctly:

[image]

The `movies.csv` from the examples:

```
movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL
tt0133093,"The Matrix",1999,Movie
tt0234215,"The Matrix Reloaded",2003,Movie;Sequel
tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie;Sequel
```

How can I combine array columns with multi labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default array delimiter is `;` so your first example correctly assigns both the Movie and Sequel labels to nodes that have `Movie;Sequel` in the LABEL column.

Not sure why you wish the delimiter to be a `|`? Your csv file would then need to look like

```
movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL
tt0133093,"The Matrix",1999,Movie
tt0234215,"The Matrix Reloaded",2003,Movie|Sequel
tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie|Sequel
```